# C++: How can one get return type of a class member function using std::invoke_result_t?

Tags: c++, return-type, member-functions, invoke-result

How can one get return type of a class member function using std::invoke_result_t in C++?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct C
{
    auto Get(void) const { return std::vector<T>{1,2,3}; }
};

int main(void)
{
 // what should one put below to make x to have type std::vector<int> ?
 std::invoke_result_t<C<int>::Get, void> x;
 //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::invoke_result_t` works on *types*, but `C<int>::Get` is not a type.  It is a non-static member function.

The *type* of `C<int>::Get` is `std::vector<int>(C<int>::)()`: Member function of `C<int>` that returns `std::vector<int>` and accepts no parameters.  That type is what you need to give to `std::invoke_result_t`.  Or rather, a pointer to it, since you can't pass raw member function types around.

Also, `std::invoke_result_t` treats the first argument type as the type of object on which to call the member function when it's dealing with pointers to member functions.

Thus you need:

```
std::invoke_result_t<std::vector<int>(C<int>::*)(), C<int>>
```

Or, if you don't want to write out the whole member function type:

```
std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&C<int>::Get), C<int>>
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfe7639be19a12c6)

---

Sidenote: `void` parameter lists are equivalent to empty parameter lists in C++.  There's no reason to explicitly specify a `void` parameter list in C++ unless you want to share a function declaration with C code.